# Sort by Parent Term name

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have two taxonomies **status** and **sub-status**. In my **sub-status** vocabulary I have **parent status** field which is a term reference pointing to the **status** field.

I created a view of sub-status taxonomy terms and I added two columns **Parent Status** and **Sub-Status**

I want to sort the views by parent status term name but it seems I don't have access to the parent terms name. I tried with adding relationships as well but no luck.

Any idea how it can be achieved?

Comment: this status sub-status parent status can be confusing. Let me make an example to see if I get this correctly

Comment: [See this Example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc3S5.jpg) so in your view you want to sort by Book title? so "Best Tires should display first" since it starts with a B, then Cleaning toyota, etc...

Comment: yes, now consider the cars as parent and books as child. I have a view of child (books) in your case and included parent in the fields. Now I want to sort it by parent (Cars) in your case but it sorts based on ids not term name. I tried with relationship but no luck

Comment: holdon, in your case, is Cars a vocabulary? or is Cars a term name of "X" vocabulary?